# pdfstringdefDisableCommands for commands with optional arguments (beamer footnote)

Tags: beamer, footnotes, pdf, bookmarks

I'm trying to strip `\cite`, `\footnote`, etc. from beamer frame titles for pdf strings. I generate bookmarks for all my frame titles using `\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{\beamer@frametitle}`, so whenever such commands arise in a frame title, they cause trouble. I know I can manually solve these using `\texorpdfstring`, but I'd rather like to have defaults that "just work", as these errors are easy to miss.

This works okay for the basic cases of `\boldmath` and `\cite{key}`, but I cannot get it to work with commands that have optional parameters such as

```
\footnote[frame]{footnote text}
```

I have tried for example

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\boldmath{}% easy case you'll find in many examples
  \def\cite{\@gobble}% supposedly does not work with optionals either
  \renewcommand<>{\footnote}[1][]{}%
}
```

but that does not work.

Minimally working example (the problem is in the PDF *bookmarks*!):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle
  \bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{\beamer@frametitle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frametitle \footnote[frame]{Footnote}}
  Frame text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This file will have a bookmark like "Frametitle [frame]Footnote". I only want "Frametitle". And I want to solve this globally, not locally by wrapping as `\texorpdfstring{\footnote[frame]{Footnote}}{}` (that works, but requires going through all problematic frames individually).
[image: Problem with bookmarks]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle
  \bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{\beamer@frametitle}}
\makeatother
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\gobbleoptandarg{om}{}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\footnote\gobbleoptandarg}%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frametitle \footnote[frame]{Footnote}}
  Frame text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```